# What type should the argument be for the run method in testcase.rb?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

For the `run(result)` method in test/unit/testcase.rb, what attribute type should my result be? It will store the result from the error and assertions from the `TestCase` class. I don't know if it should be `TestCase` object or something.

Comment: Why are you modifying the `run` method?

Comment: @razlebe: If you're retagging ruby questions to get rid of "unit", check if "testunit" is an applicable tag.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks, I will. [unit] itself is utterly useless.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a `Test::Unit::TestResult` so that it provides the `add_failure`, `add_error` and `add_assertion` methods.